# Electron/NodeJS : I can't retriving mysql table data and print them on the index.html page

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new in Electron and NodeJS development. In my desktop application I have defined as such as DAO classes  to retrieve my data from my db schema. Every class has all the usual CRUD functions (corresponding to all query they need). I.e., for my function `getAllProducts()` I defined it as follows

```
    class ProdottiDAO {
    ...
 getAllProducts(callback)
  { 
    var query = "SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE`";
     this.resultQuery = this.sqlManager.CONNECTION.query(query, null,  function(error, results, fields){
      if (error) throw error;
      return callback(results);
    });
```

- `sqlManager` is a private member just creates the connection to the DB
- `resultQuery` is a private member just should store data tables

In my `index.js` I try to retrieve my data as follows:

```
var resultQuery = [];
var prodotto = new ProdottiDAO();
prodotto.getAllProducts(function (res){
     if(res.length==0) alert("No products");
    for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
      // Stores res in resultQuery var
      resultQuery.push(res[i]);
    }
});
document.getElementById('desc-prod').innerText = resultQuery[0][0].descrizione;
```

But variable `resultQuery[0][0]` is always set as `undefined` on the **index.html** page while if I print with the console.log(resultQuery) I'm able to correctly access to the RowDataPacket structure with `resultQuery[0][0]`. What can I do to pull res data out of the callback function?

Answer (score 1):

I see two obvious problems:

1. Database access is usually asynchronous. If that holds true for your application, then you probably have to 'await' the result. Then it would be expected that the `resultQuery` array is empty when you actually access it
2. Such DAO implementations are usually running on the main process, the node.js part of your application. Here you create the DAO on the client (render process) and I wonder if the DAO is really able to access the database. Probably not, maybe it fails with an error because of that and that's why you see nothing.

I'd keep the `ProdottiDAO` on the main process and define a simple ipcChannel so that client and backend can communicate. The client would send an message via `ipc.sendSync('find-all-products')` and the main process would listen to that, execute the query and return the data with `event.result = resultQuery`.

(can be solved asynchronously but this is the easier way to just get it working and improve later)

Comment: Hi Andreas. Thanks for your answer. Should not the callback function be the "waiting function" of my call? If I change `resultQuery.push(res[i]);` with `printToHTMLpage(table, res[i])` I can see all my data. So the results are available but in callback body only. Isn't it correct?  
I have no idea how can use ipcChannel, but I will see the docs.

Comment: Yes, it looks like your query function on the sqlmanager is blocking (synchronous). That's surprising, but well. It's more likely that you have to check carefully what can be used on the render process (the client) and what has to executed on the main process (node.js). And both process can only exchange data via IPC, they are totally isolated from each other.